# How to center custom tabbar item on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-x

I have an app where I created a custom tabbar item in a UITabbarController, that someone can press to take a picture, and it looks like it does below.

[image: Image for iPhone 8s]

That is exactly what I want, the problem is that when I test it on an iPhone X, the tabbar item for the camera looks lower then I would like, for example:

[image: Image for iPhone X]

I have tried a couple of things to fix this, such as fixing the height of the tabbar in the viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but it messed with the tabbar on the iPhone 8. I also made sure that the "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" is selected, but it still doesn't work.

[image]

I also tried to change the frame of the tabbar item, but that doesn't work either.

This is the code that I used for the custom tabbar Controller:

```
    import UIKit

class OtherTabController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupBtn()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }





    func setupBtn() {
        let centerBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 45, height: 45))

        var centerBtnFrame = centerBtn.frame
        centerBtnFrame.origin.y = (view.bounds.height - centerBtnFrame.height) - 2
        centerBtnFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - centerBtnFrame.size.width/2
        centerBtn.frame = centerBtnFrame

        centerBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        view.addSubview(centerBtn)
        let centerImg = UIImage(named: "Other")

        centerBtn.setBackgroundImage(centerImg, for: .normal)
        centerBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centerBtnAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }


    @objc private func centerBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Camera")
        cameraAction()
    }

    func cameraAction() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a Photo", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(takePhotoAction)
        let selectFromAlbumAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from Album", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(selectFromAlbumAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //OtherTabController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If there is anything else I could help with, please ask. Thank you

EDIT:

I tried to make the y view the same as the super view but all it did was move the button to the top of the screen.

```
    var centerBtnFrame = centerBtn.frame
centerBtnFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.minY //Make centerBtn' top equal to that of view's
centerBtnFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - centerBtnFrame.size.width/2
centerBtn.frame = centerBtnFrame
```

[image]

If you need any more info, please ask. Thank you

---

Edit: 
With the help of @Revanth Kausikan, I decided to create a custom tabbar with a view and a few buttons. It works very well in my opinion. It looks a little rough around the edges, but this is just a test for now.

[image: What it looks like]

Here is the code for the view:

```
    import UIKit

class ItemScene: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var customTab: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var twoBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var oneBtn: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    @IBAction func cameraBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Camera")
    }


    @IBAction func twoBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
        print("Two")
    }


    @IBAction func oneBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("One")
    }


}
```

this is the code for the second ViewController:

```
    import UIKit

class TestingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var oneBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var twoBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func cameraBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Camera")
    }


    @IBAction func twoBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        print("Two")
    }

    @IBAction func oneBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegueToReturnBack()
        print("One")
    }
}


extension UIViewController {
    func performSegueToReturnBack()  {
        if let nav = self.navigationController {
            nav.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has anything else to add it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Y point of button frame must be the same as that of it's super view (i.e. tab bar here).

If you've not created an outlet for the tab bar, first do so.

1. Ctrl (or right) click and drag from your tab bar in the storyboard to its associated view controller, to create an outlet. (assume that I'm naming it as `tabBar`)
2. now try this:

```
var centerBtnFrame = centerBtn.frame
let tabBarFrame = self.convert(tabBar.frame, to: view) 
centerBtnFrame.origin.y = tabBarFrame.minY //Make centerBtn' top equal to that of tabBar's
centerBtnFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - centerBtnFrame.size.width/2
centerBtn.frame = centerBtnFrame
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
var centerBtnFrame = centerBtn.frame
centerBtnFrame.origin.y = view.height - tabBar.height //This is the same logic as you've used for fixing x value of centerBtnFrame.
centerBtnFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - centerBtnFrame.size.width/2
centerBtn.frame = centerBtnFrame
```

Yet another approach is to go back to the constraints, and make sure the elements and the base view are within the safe area.

If my guess is right (since you've not provided details about the constraints in the question), you've set the base view (the view that is in the bottom/base, holding all other elements on it) to fit itself with the entire view are of the view controller. Consider changing it to fit itself within the safe area.

Let me know the results.

**EDIT**

My opinion on your new attempt: It's really good, and I see that you are now able to customize it a lot more.

To improve it, you can try these:

Here, there are three views that are clickable in nature. we can use this to increase the interactive area as per our wish, to provide a natural experience for the user.
[image]

Here are it's constraints:
[image]

Other than these suggestions, I don't think I need to provide any. Your method is self sufficient for your implementation idea.

:)

Comment: #Revanth Kausikan Sorry but this did not work. All this did was move the center camera button to the top of the phone. See above.

Comment: I tried what you recommended, but sadly it turned out like before, the button was at the top. I created an outlet, and i am using the frames, but it still isn't working.

Comment: hmm.. strange. It'll be nice if you can share your storyboard constraints.

Comment: The storyboard doesn't have any constraints, because there is nothing on the storyboard.

Comment: technically, a custom tabbar item. I am using UITabBarController.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193231/discussion-between-revanth-kausikan-and-newby).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code working 100% ...
Declare the button
    var menuButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

           super.viewDidLoad()
           setupMiddleButton()
    }

    //create the method
    func setupMiddleButton(flag:String) {

            menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
            var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
            menuButtonFrame.origin.y = tabBar.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height
            menuButtonFrame.origin.x = tabBar.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
            menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
            menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            menuButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
            tabBar.addSubview(menuButton)

            menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
            menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Homenormal"), for: .normal)
            menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        }
    //button methods inside add background colour
     @objc private func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
            menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            selectedIndex = 2
            print("menuButtonActio=\(sender.tag)")
        }
    //next Tabbar didselect
      override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

            let Selected_index = tabBar.items?.lastIndex(of: item)
            print("selectedIndex123=\(Selected_index)")

            if Selected_index == 0 {
                menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            }
            else if Selected_index == 1 {

                menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            }
            else if Selected_index == 2 {

                menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

            }
            else if Selected_index == 3 {

                menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            }
            else if Selected_index == 4 {

                menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                menuButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            }

       }
```

Comment: Sorry its not working for iPhone X Notch devices (iPhone X, iPhone 11 etc)Its not working at first time. Button layout comes down.